# Getting a "NAN" error message within a UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having major issues with an error message within a UITextField. I have a IBAction buttontap id sender setup to when I tap a UITextField and tap buttontap, it adds a value +1 to the UITextField that was selected. My issue is my UITextField that I have setup to come up with a percentage between two UITextfields is giving me a "NAN" error message when I tap other UITextFields. I thought I had this problem solved until I added more code. Here is my current code:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender { 
    int value = [currentText.text intValue] + 1;
    currentText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",value];

    int n7 = [tex.text intValue]; 
    int n8 = [tex2.text intValue];
    int n9 = [tex3.text intValue];
    int n10 = [tex4.text intValue];
    int n11 = [tex5.text intValue];
    int n12 = [tex6.text intValue];
    int r = n7 + n8 + n9 + n10 + n11 + n12;
    NSString *rn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",r];
    [tex13 setText:rn]; 

    int n1 = [tex7.text intValue]; 
    int n2 = [tex8.text intValue];
    int n3 = [tex9.text intValue];
    int n4 = [tex10.text intValue];
    int n5 = [tex11.text intValue];
    int n6 = [tex12.text intValue];
    int s = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6;
    NSString *sn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",s];
    [tex14 setText:sn]; 



    float firstFloat = [self.tex15.text floatValue]; 
    float secondFloat = [self.tex16.text floatValue]; 
    float answer = secondFloat / firstFloat * 100; 
    self.tex20.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",answer];   
}
```

Comment: does firstFloat evaluate to 0? if so you are getting a "divide by zero" error.

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you're showing us.  We don't know what the values of `tex`, `tex2`, ... `tex16` are.  If they're uninitialized or `tex15` is 0, that would explain it.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Do I need to use an if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Is it NAN or NaN? NaN stands for not a number and will be printed when the result of your math leads to something that can't be expressed numerically. As pointed out in a comment, dividing by zero will give you a NaN.

Addressing it is pretty straightforward: Figure out where you're dividing by zero, or whatever is causing the NaN, and use if/else statements to test those values. Then substitute a new value or pass an error message string to the label explaining the situation.

edit:

That might look something like this:

```
    float firstFloat = [self.tex15.text floatValue]; 
    float secondFloat = [self.tex16.text floatValue]; 

    NSString *labelOutput;

    if (firstFloat == 0.0)
    {
        labelOutput = NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"Error while dividing by zero");
    }

    else 
    {
        float answer = secondFloat / firstFloat * 100; 
        labelOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f%%",answer];

    }

    self.tex20.text = labelOutput;
```

Comment: Sure, there's a simple one for you.